# Parsing an xml RSS feed file

Tags: xml

What I would like to achieve is to receive an email with the failures of my VPS. I tried to do that by downloading an rss feed XML file from my VPS provider which contains all the failures, down states etc. of their servers.

Once I downloaded it, I would like to parse it in order to see if my Virtual Host number is included in any of the entries of the XML file. If yes, I should receive an email containing the entire entry that contains my Virtual Host number (well, this is not a problem at all using `sendmail`).
I have been unsuccessfully trying to use a simple and dirty `wget` and `grep`.

This is the file I would like to parse: http://www.hetzner-status.de/en.atom

Comment: If you want to parse XML use an XML parser instead of grep. Libraries are available for every common language. Here's something to get you started: [How do I parse XML in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1912434/1013470)

Comment: Are you really asking us to help you parse a file we can't see? Anyway, don't try to use regular expressions to parse XML files, it might [wake up Tony](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1081936).

Comment: Thankyou for these start points. http://www.hetzner-status.de/en.atom this is the file I would like to parse.

Comment: @Marco: thank you for the suggestion, I'm very ignorant abouth python so I'd rather not using it, I would prefer a bash script. I hope I'm not being too choosy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The utility you're looking for is [`xml2`](http://ofb.net/~egnor/xml2/).

The xml2 command will convert an XML document into flat text. Using the URL you you gave as an example, here's a snippet of the conversion.

```
$ curl -sL http://www.hetzner-status.de/en.atom | xml2 | head
/feed/@xmlns=http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom
/feed/title=Hetzner Online AG - Status-Webseite
/feed/id=http://www.hetzner-status.de/
/feed/link/@href=http://www.hetzner-status.de/en.atom
/feed/link/@rel=self
/feed/link/@type=application/atom+xml
/feed/link
/feed/link/@href=http://www.hetzner-status.de/
/feed/updated=2014-01-24T18:00:04Z
/feed/author/name=Hetzner Online AG
```

Each line is a key, which is an XML path, separated from its value by `=`. You should be able to get the rest using `grep`/`cut` or `awk`.

Comment: Thank you very much bahamat! I will check this out within tomorrow and I'll let you know how it went, but it looks exactly what I was looking for.